# Dropdown With filtered value after text entered or edited in VB6

Tags: combobox, vb6, filtering

I need dropdown list with text field where i can type and dropdown will filter on basis of text.
Like I have data of all countries name and I type "AME" in my textbox so only country containing word "AME" it will show list of countries containing character "AME" only and I can select from list (Like America).

I tried using combo box

```vb
Private Sub Combo1_GotFocus()
    Combo1.AddItem "America"
    Combo1.AddItem "Europe"
    Combo1.AddItem "China"
    Combo1.AddItem "INDIA"
    Combo1.AddItem "London"
End Sub
```

There are 2 issue I am facing

1. When combo box got focus the dropdown is not opening i have to click on arrow
2. When I type "LO" I need dropdown to filter list with containing data with text "LO" only
   Like I type "ch" it will only show china and can select china only

Comment: For the dropdown you can use this API code from VBnet: http://vbnet.mvps.org/index.html?code/comboapi/combolistdropdown.htm but my VB6 is very rusty so I can't really help with the rest I'm afraid.

Comment: thank you. This is shows how to enable or disable dropdown.

Comment: If you don't want to use the api call, or if it's not appropriate (eg, the api call isn't applicable for all combo styles), you can open the list without using the mouse via the keystrokes Alt-Down arrow.

Comment: @NEo I would recommend using a third-party control that already have these features built in.

Comment: where to get thirdparty controL?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, I like using third-party controls for features that are not included with standard controls.  However, a combination of API calls and the KeyPress event may get you close enough.

For easier coding this solution depends upon a Recordset containing country names.

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" _
   (ByVal hwnd As Long, _
    ByVal wMsg As Long, _
    ByVal wParam As Long, _
    lParam As Any) As Long

Private Const CB_SHOWDROPDOWN = &H14F

Private m_Countries As ADODB.Recordset

Private Sub Form_Load()
   Set m_Countries = New ADODB.Recordset
   m_Countries.Fields.Append "Country", adVarChar, 50
   m_Countries.Open
   m_Countries.AddNew "Country", "America"
   m_Countries.AddNew "Country", "Europe"
   m_Countries.AddNew "Country", "China"
   m_Countries.AddNew "Country", "Chicago"
   m_Countries.AddNew "Country", "INDIA"
   m_Countries.AddNew "Country", "London"
   m_Countries.MoveFirst
   
   Combo1.Text = ""
   
   FillCombo
End Sub

Private Sub Combo1_GotFocus()
   SendMessage Combo1.hwnd, CB_SHOWDROPDOWN, True, ByVal 0
End Sub

Private Sub Combo1_LostFocus()
   SendMessage Combo1.hwnd, CB_SHOWDROPDOWN, False, ByVal 0
End Sub

Private Sub Combo1_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
   Dim Filter As String
   
   If KeyAscii > 31 Then
      Filter = Combo1.Text & Chr(KeyAscii)             'typed char
   ElseIf KeyAscii = 8 And Combo1.Text <> "" Then
      Filter = Left(Combo1.Text, Len(Combo1.Text) - 1) 'backspace
   End If

   If Filter <> "" Then
      m_Countries.Filter = "Country LIKE '" & Filter & "%'"
   Else
      m_Countries.Filter = ""
   End If

   FillCombo
End Sub

Private Sub FillCombo()
   Dim i As Integer
   
   'to avoid interferring with the textbox of the combo don't use the Clear method
   For i = Combo1.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
      Combo1.RemoveItem i
   Next

   Do While Not (m_Countries.BOF Or m_Countries.EOF)
      Combo1.AddItem m_Countries.Fields("Country").Value
      m_Countries.MoveNext
   Loop
End Sub
```